# Make server validation using redux-form and Fetch API

Tags: validation, redux, es6-promise, fetch-api, redux-form

How to make server-side validation using [redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form) and Fetch API?
There are "[Submit Validation](http://erikras.github.io/redux-form/#/examples/submit-validation?_k=jk9zmm)" demo provided in the docs which says that recommended way to do server side validation is to return a promise from the onSubmit function. But where should I place that promise?
As I understood onSubmit function should be my action.

```
<form onSubmit={this.props.addWidget}>...
```

Where this.props.addWidget is actually my action, provided below.

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
...
function fetchAddWidget(widget, workspace) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(requestAddWidget(widget, workspace));
        return fetch.post(`/service/workspace/${workspace}/widget`, widget)
            .then(parseJSON)
            .then(json => {
                dispatch(successAddWidget(json, workspace));
                DataManager.handleSubscribes(json);
            })
            .catch(error => popupErrorMessages(error));
    }
}

export function addWidget(data, workspace) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return dispatch(fetchAddWidget(data, workspace));
    }
}
```

As you see I use fetch API. I expected that fetch will return promise and redux-form will catch it but that doesn't work. How to make it work with promise from [example](http://erikras.github.io/redux-form/#/examples/submit-validation?_k=jk9zmm)?

Also from the demo I can not understand what should be provided in this.props.handleSubmit function. Demo does not explain this part, as for me.

Comment: This issue may be helpful: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/256

Comment: Oops, I was thinking of the example in https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/291

Comment: @memeLab yes, you are right! Thank you for links

Comment: @Denis what was your final solution to this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's my take on using fetch based on the example at http://erikras.github.io/redux-form/#/examples/submit-validation.

> - ...but where should I place that promise?
> - ...what should be provided in this.props.handleSubmit?

The detail is in the comments below; sorry that the code blocks require a bit of scrolling to read :/

---

#### `components/submitValidation.js`

```js
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { myHandleSubmit, show as showResults } from '../redux/modules/submission';

class SubmitValidationForm extends Component {
  // the following three props are all provided by the reduxForm() wrapper / decorator
  static propTypes = {
    // the field names we passed in the wrapper;
    // each field is now an object with properties:
    // value, error, touched, dirty, etc
    // and methods onFocus, onBlur, etc
    fields: PropTypes.object.isRequired,

    // handleSubmit is _how_ to handle submission:
    // eg, preventDefault, validate, etc
    // not _what_ constitutes or follows success or fail.. that's up to us

    // I must pass a submit function to this form, but I can either:

    // a) import or define a function in this component (see above), then: 
    //   `<form onSubmit={ this.props.handleSubmit(myHandleSubmit) }>`, or

    // b) pass that function to this component as 
    //   `<SubmitValidationForm onSubmit={ myHandleSubmit } etc />`, then 
    //   `<form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>`
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,

    // redux-form listens for `reject({_error: 'my error'})`, we receive `this.props.error`
    error: PropTypes.string
  };

  render() {
    const { fields: { username, password }, error, handleSubmit } = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(myHandleSubmit) }>

        <input type="text" {...username} />
        {
            // this can be read as "if touched and error, then render div"
            username.touched && username.error && <div className="form-error">{ username.error }</div>
        }

        <input type="password" {...password} />
        { password.touched && password.error && <div className="form-error">{ password.error }</div> }

        {
          // this is the generic error, passed through as { _error: 'something wrong' }
          error && <div className="text-center text-danger">{ error }</div>
        }

        // not sure why in the example @erikras uses 
        // `onClick={ handleSubmit }` here.. I suspect a typo.
        // because I'm using `type="submit"` this button will trigger onSubmit
        <button type="submit">Log In</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

// this is the Higher Order Component I've been referring to 
// as the wrapper, and it may also be written as a @decorator
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'submitValidation',
  fields: ['username', 'password'] // we send only field names here
})(SubmitValidationForm);
```

---

#### `../redux/modules/submission.js`

```js
// (assume appropriate imports)

function postToApi(values) {
  return fetch( API_ENDPOINT, {
    credentials: 'include',
    mode: 'cors',
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify({values}),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFToken': CSRF_TOKEN
    }
  }).then( response => Promise.all([ response, response.json()] ));
}

export const myHandleSubmit = (values, dispatch) => {
  dispatch(startLoading());

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // postToApi is a wrapper around fetch
    postToApi(values)
      .then(([ response, json ]) => {
        dispatch(stopLoading());

        // your statuses may be different, I only care about 202 and 400
        if (response.status === 202) {
          dispatch(showResults(values));
          resolve();
        }
        else if (response.status === 400) {
          // here I expect that the server will return the shape:
          // {
          //   username: 'User does not exist',
          //   password: 'Wrong password',
          //   _error: 'Login failed!'
          // }
          reject(json.errors);
        }
        else {
          // we're not sure what happened, but handle it:
          // our Error will get passed straight to `.catch()`
          throw(new Error('Something went horribly wrong!'));
        }
      })
      .catch( error => {
        // Otherwise unhandled server error
        dispatch(stopLoading());
        reject({ _error: error });
      });
  });
};
```

---

Please chime in with comments if I've missed something / misinterpreted, etc, and I'll amend :)

Comment: I think it may be unnecessary to wrap postToApi in another promise.. see https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/256#issuecomment-155859342 for an example.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I had a similar question but on implementing your solution, my code is running into the catch block even though the API is returning successfully.

The error being returned in the catch block is `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined(…)"`. I am not sure where this is coming from redux-form. 

Any ideas on what I might be missing?

Also, to your above comment, would you recommend editing the code to remove `return new Promise` piece?

Comment: @geoboy, in your fetch() wrapper are you returning `.then( response => Promise.all([ response, response.json()] ))`? Note that it passes `[response, json]` to the next .then.. if you're doing something significantly different, then that would explain the undefined error (which is not specifically a redux-form error).

Comment: @geoboy, I had trouble getting the simpler format to work, which is like `.then(() => {}, errors => {})` as seen here: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/256#issuecomment-157103662.  I'll revise this answer next time I implement it :)

Comment: @geoboy not sure if this is related, and should form the basis of a new question for me, but I'm finding that if my code has a simple syntax error _after_ "the promise has successfully resolved", then that error is getting caught by the `.catch()`, which inconveniently loses the stacktrace :( still working to understand the magic :)

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that [there are undocumented property](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/256#issuecomment-157771717) `returnRejectedSubmitPromise` which must be set to true.

Comment: I'm still unclear on when this is required; I don't need it using the implementation in my answer